# C++ Inheritance not taking an enum

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

I'm trying to figure out basic inheritance. But I seem unable to get the enum to take. It just responds with a smiley face and nothing.

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong so I'm afraid I'll have to just throw all my code at you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Discipline {
   COMPUTER_SCIENCE, Computer_SCIENCE_AND_INNOVATION
};

const string DISCIPLINE_STRINGS[2] = { "Computer Science",
   "Computer Science and Innovation",
};

class Person {
public:
    Person(){cout << "Person object created using the default Person constructor\n";};
    Person(const string& name, Discipline type){pName = name; pType = type;};
    ~Person(){cout << "Person object destroyed\n";};
    string pName;
    string pType;
};

class Faculty: public Person {
public:
    Faculty();
    Faculty(const string& name, Discipline type) {pName = name; pType = type; cout << "Faculty object created using the alternative Faculty constructor\n";};
    ~Faculty(){cout << "Faculty object destroyed!";};
    string getName(){return pName;};
    string getDepartment(){return pType;};
};

class Student: public Person {
public:
    Student();
    Student(const string& name, Discipline type) {pName = name; pType = type; cout << "Student object created using the alternative Student constructor\n";};
    ~Student(){cout << "Student object destroyed!";};
    string getMajor(){return pType;};
    string getName(){return pName;};
};



int main()
{
   Faculty prof("Name1", COMPUTER_SCIENCE);
   Student stu(" Name2", Computer_SCIENCE_AND_INNOVATION);

   cout << endl << "I, " << stu.getName() << ", am majoring in " << stu.getMajor() << "." << endl;
   cout << "I am taking CSI 240 with Prof. " << prof.getName() << ", who teaches "
        << prof.getDepartment() << " courses." << endl << endl;
   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect your program to print instead? If you want it to print something from that `Discipline_Strings ` array, make sure you mention that array somewhere associated with the printing code. Currently, you define it, and then never use it. Also, what makes you think this problem has anything to do with inheritance, besides that your homework this week is about inheritance?

Comment: what is the expected output?? what did u get ??

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the enum instead of the actual string.
You should use the enum to index into `DISCIPLINE_STRINGS`.

When you set the type string do this:
`pType = DISCIPLINE_STRINGS[type]`